# How to make that when I type in VSCode my text not goes on one line all the time

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, typing

The issue that makes my life harder is that while typing in VSCode my codes moves 'right' all the time, which is not convenient when I type long sentences. Tell me please how to adjust this setting that when I reach the end of my window text goes a line down automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting you're trying to modify is "word wrap".
Just go to File > Preferences > Settings, search "Word Wrap" and it will appear.
There are several options, but I think that the one that achieves the behaviour you want is just setting it to "on".